# Reading crontab-like syntax from a database to execute functions

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a database of scheduled tasks that'll be run based on the normal crontab-like syntax eg. min hour dom month dow (in separate table fields).

I'm not all that good at explaining myself, however what I would like to do is just set up one actual system crontab every minute, then that PHP file will then parse my database to look for all the scheduled tasks with crontab syntax, then when it hits the right time/day/etc, execute a function..... So, for example, if I set */10 for the minutes, then * for the rest, the function should be executed every 10 minutes, checked from the every minute running system cron.

To be honest, I am not sure how I go about actually parsing the database crontab-like syntax via PHP - like, take the example I just give, every 10 minutes. I know I'd need to record the last timestamp of the said task was run and the next timestamp it will be run - however, it's just initially working out when this next timestamp will be based on the crontab syntax I'll have issues with.

Hope I have explained this clearly, and thanks in advance.

Comment: If the actual cron job runs every minute, there's no need to track when your tasks were last run. For example, if a task is intended to run every 10 minutes, you will know to run it when the current minute is 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, or 50.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/dragonmantank/cron-expression, its a simple cron expression parser that looks like it'll work well for you.